# PHP form validation not working (Always says input is empty)

Tags: php, forms, validation

I have written some code that takes information from a submitted form and adds it into a table in a database. The code works without any problems for adding the information into the database, but I am having problems with the form validation. I have written some code to display an error message if any fields in the form are left empty, but the error message appears whether the field is empty or not. Here is the code for the form:

```
<form action = "add.php" method = "post">

    <div class = "form-group">
        <label for = "item_name">Item Name</label>
        <input type = "text" class = "form-control" name = "item_name" id = "item_name" placeholder="Item Name">
    </div>

    <div class = "form-group">
        <label for = "item_desc">Item Description</label>
        <input type = "text" class = "form-control" name = "item_desc" id = "item_desc" placeholder="Item Description">
    </div>

    <div class = "form-group">
        <label for = "item_price">Item Price</label>
        <input type = "text" class = "form-control" name = "item_price" id = "item_price" placeholder="Item Price">
    </div>

    <div class = "form-group">
        <label for = "item_cat">Item Category</label>
        <select class = "form-control" name = "item_cat" id = "item_cat">
            <?php

            //Get categories and names from the category table
            $query = "SELECT category_id, category_title FROM item_category ORDER BY category_title";
            $result = mysqli_query($db,$query);
            while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
            {
                print_r($row);
                echo "<option value = '" . $row['category_id'] . "'>";
                echo $row['category_title'];
                echo "</option>";
            }
            ?>
        </select>
    </div>

        <div class = "row">

            <div class = "col-sm-6"><input type = "submit" class="btn btn-info" value="Submit"></div>
            <div class = "col-sm-6"><a href = "admin.php" class = "btn btn-default" role = "button">Return</a></div>

        </div>

</form>
```

And here is the code for the validation:

```
//A function to remove unnecessary data and turn special characters into their escape codes
function testInput($data)
{
    $data = trim($data);
    $data = stripslashes($data);
    $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
    return $data;
}

//a function to display an error and exit
function dispErr($error)
{
    echo $error;
    exit();
}

if($_SESSION['authuser']!=1)
{
    echo "Access denied";
    exit();
}

//Make sure all values are set
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
{
    //Check no fields are blank
    if(empty($POST["item_name"]))
    {
        dispErr("Item name must not be empty");
    }
    if(empty($POST['item_desc']))
    {
        dispErr("Item description must not be empty");
    }
    if(empty($POST['item_cat']))
    {
        dispErr("Item category must not be empty");
    }
    if(empty($POST['item_price']))
    {
        dispErr("Item price must not be empty");
    }

    $item_name = testInput($_POST['item_name']);
    $item_desc = testInput($_POST['item_desc']);
    $item_cat  = testInput($_POST['item_cat']);
    $item_price = testInput($_POST['item_price']);
}
else
{
    exit();
}
```

Comment: It's `$_POST` not `$POST`  Your validation tests are missing the underscores

Comment: Yeah that's it, what a silly mistake. Thanks!